# Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests. ON CopyDocumentSet

Tags: 2010

I have tried everything with this issue, but cant find the error.

THe structure of my site is like this

1. Meetings  (SiteCollection, RootWeb)

   1.1 BoardOFDirectors (subsite)

   1.1.1 20120101 (subsite)

   1.1.2 20120202 (subsite)

Inside meetings there is a list called meetings.
Inside each subsite there is a list called agenda points with document sets.

I created a custom action to copy agenda points from one meeting site to the next one.

I am getting the following exception in the CopyTo method.
As you can see there I set the allowunsafeupdates=true everywhere. 
What am I missing??

Updates are currently disallowed on GET requests.  To allow updates on a GET, set the 'AllowUnsafeUpdates' property on SPWeb.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Logger.LogDebug("CopyAgendaPointToNextMeetingWithAttachments", "Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)", "BEGIN");

            string source = Request.Url.ToString();
            string state = Request.GetQueryStringValue(MeetingsCommon.Constants.QUERYSTRINGPARAMETER_STATE_NAME);
            string statusMessage = Request.GetQueryStringValue(MeetingsCommon.Constants.QUERYSTRINGPARAMETER_MESSAGE_NAME);
            this.litMessage.Text = statusMessage;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state))
                return;

            using (SPLongOperation operation = new SPLongOperation(this.Page))
            {
                SPWeb currentWeb = SPContext.Current.Web;
                SPSite currentSite = currentWeb.Site;
                try
                {                    
                    operation.Begin();
                    currentSite.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
                    currentSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;  

                    string listID = Request.QueryString[MeetingsCommon.Constants.QUERYSTRINGPARAMETER_LISTID_NAME];
                    string listItemID = Request.QueryString[MeetingsCommon.Constants.QUERYSTRINGPARAMETER_ID_NAME];  
                    string webappUrl = currentSite.WebApplication.GetResponseUri(currentSite.Zone).ToString();
                    source = source.Replace(webappUrl.ToLower(), currentWeb.Url.ToLower() + "/");

                    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(() =>
                    {
                        SPList currentList = currentWeb.GetSafeListByGuid(new Guid(listID));
                        SPListItem item = currentList.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(listItemID));
                        SPWeb siteCollectionRootWeb = currentWeb.ParentWeb.ParentWeb.Site.RootWeb;
                        string type = currentWeb.Name.Substring(0, 2);
                        SPList listMeetingsRoot = siteCollectionRootWeb.GetSafeListByName(Meetings.Common.Constants.LISTS_MEETINGCALENDAR_NAME);


                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = string.Concat(
                            "<Where>",
                            "<And>",
                            "<BeginsWith>",
                                "<FieldRef Name='" + Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_TEXT_TITLE_NAME + "' />",
                                "<Value Type='Text'>" + type + "</Value>",
                            "</BeginsWith>",
                            "<Gt>",
                                " <FieldRef Name='" + Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_EVENTDATE_NAME + "' />",
                                "<Value Type='DateTime'><Today /></Value>",
                            "</Gt>",                                   
                            "</And>",
                            "</Where>");
                        query.RowLimit = 1;

                        SPListItemCollection itemsMeetings = listMeetingsRoot.GetItems(query);
                        if (itemsMeetings.Count == 1)
                        {
                            SPFieldUrlValue value = new SPFieldUrlValue(itemsMeetings[0][Meetings.Common.Constants.FIELDS_MEETINGSITEURL_NAME].ToString());
                            string urlOfNextMeetingSite = value.Url;
                            using (SPSite nextMeetingSite = new SPSite(urlOfNextMeetingSite))
                            {
                                using (SPWeb nextMeetingWeb = nextMeetingSite.OpenWeb())
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        nextMeetingSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                        nextMeetingWeb.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                        nextMeetingWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                        SPList targetList = nextMeetingWeb.GetSafeListByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTS_NAME);
                                        SPDocumentLibrary targetDocumentLibrary = nextMeetingWeb.GetSafeDocumentLibraryByName(MeetingsCommon.Constants.LISTS_AGENDAPOINTS_NAME);
                                        SPContentTypeId targetCTId = targetList.ContentTypes.BestMatch(new SPContentTypeId(MeetingsCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_AGENDAPOINT_ID));
                                        string id = itemsMeetings[0]["UniqueId"].ToString();

                                        DocumentSet sourceDocumentSet = DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(item.Folder);
                                        DocumentSet targetDocumentSet = null;
                                        if (sourceDocumentSet != null)
                                        {
                                            targetDocumentSet = sourceDocumentSet.CopyTo(targetList.RootFolder, targetCTId);
                                            SPListItem destinationListItem = targetDocumentSet.Item;
                                            destinationListItem[MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSRECURRENT_NAME] = "False";
                                            destinationListItem[MeetingsCommon.Constants.FIELDS_AGENDAPOINTSCOPYATTACHMENTS_NAME] = "False";
                                            destinationListItem.Update();
                                            statusMessage = string.Format(HelperFunctions.GetResourceString(MeetingsCommon.Constants.RESOURCES_FILE_NAME, "Message_CopyAgendaPoint"), nextMeetingWeb.Url, nextMeetingWeb.Name);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception)
                                    {
                                        throw;
                                    }
                                    finally
                                    {
                                        nextMeetingWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                        nextMeetingWeb.ParentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                        nextMeetingSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                                    }                                    
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            statusMessage = HelperFunctions.GetResourceString(MeetingsCommon.Constants.RESOURCES_FILE_NAME, "Message_CopyAgendaPointNoNextSiteFound");
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.LogError("CopyAgendaPointToNextMeetingWithAttachments", "Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)", ex);
                    statusMessage = ex.Message;
                }
                finally
                {
                    statusMessage = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(statusMessage);                                    
                    currentWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    currentSite.RootWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    currentSite.WebApplication.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = true;   
                    operation.End(source, Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPRedirectFlags.DoNotEncodeUrl, HttpContext.Current, "&state=completed&message=" + statusMessage);
                }
                Logger.LogDebug("CopyAgendaPointToNextMeetingWithAttachments", "Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)", "END");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no get requests allowed for the createdocumentset or copyto methods

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IN/sharepoint2010programming/thread/b2d13a96-f32b-41c5-a1ac-0c9280921f59